# Express NodeJS returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have two middleware functions defined

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

const notFound = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(404);
  next(error);
};

const errorHandler = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
  res.status(statusCode);
  const errorResponse =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? { message: err.message }
      : {
          message: err.message,
          stack: err.stack
        };
  res.status(statusCode).json(errorResponse);
};

export { notFound, errorHandler };
```

and I am using it in my server like

```
import { errorHandler, notFound } from './middleware/errorMiddleware';


app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);
```

however the response is in HTML format and not in JSON

Comment: can you post the HTML response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use):

> Error-handling middleware always takes ***four*** arguments. You must provide four arguments to identify it as an error-handling middleware function. Even if you don’t need to use the `next` object, you must specify it to maintain the signature. Otherwise, the next object will be interpreted as regular middleware and will fail to handle errors.

Your code:

> ```
> const errorHandler = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response) => {
> ```

… only takes three arguments.